# I try to upload a file, API Silex

Tags: php, html, post, apache2, silex

I use PHP/Silex to do an API.
All my code work exept one road...
Here my *index.php* of my API code where I've a problem:

```
require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';  
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
$app = new Silex\Application();

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;


$app->post('/upload', function (Request $request) use ($app)
       {
         $file = $request->files->get('upload');                                                                     
         if ($file == NULL)   
       {
     $send = json_encode(array("status" => "Fail"));
     return $app->json($send, 500);
       }
     else
       {
     $file->move(__DIR__.'/../files', $file->getClientOriginalName());
     $send = json_encode(array("status" => "Ok"));
             return $app->json($send, 200);
       }
       });
$app->run();
```

When I comment this line `$file->move(__DIR__.'/../files', $file->getClientOriginalName());` the program return status, but if I let this line. I've a `text/html` in response where we can read,

```
..Whoops, looks like something went wrong
FileException in File.php line 134:
Unable to create the "/var/www/api-picShary/web/../files" directory
in File.php line 134
at File->getTargetFile('/var/www/api-picShary/web/../files',  'awesome.png') in UploadedFile.php line 239
at UploadedFile->move('/var/www/api-picShary/web/../files', 'awesome.png') in index.php line 79
at {closure}( object( Request))
at call_user_func_array( object( Closure), array( object( Request))) in HttpKernel.php line 145
at HttpKernel->handleRaw( object( Request), '1') in HttpKernel.php line 66
at HttpKernel->handle( object( Request), '1', true) in Application.php line 543
at Application->handle( object( Request)) in Application.php line 520
```

at Application->run() in index.php line 86...

I use a form to send my file :

```
< form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
< input type="file" name="upload">
< input type="submit">
< /form>
```

Comment: Did you make sure the webserver user can write to the files directory? You can also try to enable debug mode (```$app['debug'] = true;```) and you'll have a better error message.

Comment: @mTorres Yes, he can (chmod 777 to be sure and chown www-data) and the debug mode is enable but nothing has changed...

Comment: @mTorres edit: I restart my server, and $app['debug'] work

Answer (score 2):

the problem had php.ini , I had to change the upload_max_filesize
post_max_size

/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/php.ini

Work

End